# Synonym for barrage of information

Tags: synonyms

Help with describing constant superficial material.  I'm trying to relate the feeling of being overwhelmed by continual triviality. For example, pop culture, or celebrities' lives scrutinized and broadcast over multiple media.  Insignificant information aggressively promulgated to the detriment of society.

Comment: The situation of 'aggressively prominent' 'superficial material' causing one to be 'overwhelmed' is difficult to express in one word. I think you have expressed it very well yourself.

Comment: They're forms of spam: **unsolicited or undesired electronic messages**. eMail spamming is only one form of spam. Companies are using gossip, trivia, DIY info, lurid stories, etc. -- as clickbait (with the complete cooperation of search engines, with which they hold business contracts), in order to attract the necessary attention in order to advertise their products. Profiteering is the motive for it. Advertising is something you will never see the end of, in this sort of economic system. Years ago (before internet) they spammed TV shows with inane and extremely annoying ads. It works for them

Comment: Did you look at a thesaurus? But also [Glut](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glut:_Mastering_Information_Through_the_Ages)

Comment: OP's research would be helpful.

Comment: a din or even a cacophony of info

Comment: 'A sea of banality' has been used more than a few times.

Comment: "Bumf" perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

A torrent of noise?

That's just a suggestion; as comments have suggested, the precise nature of what you want to describe does not seem to lend itself easily to a succinct word or phrase.

Answer (score 0):

One might characterize the information passing by as possessing "a low signal-to-noise ratio", or say that the signal is overwhelmed by the static.